# How can i install LightGBM? Error about Could not find OpenMP_C in Mac

Tags: gcc, cmake, lightgbm

I am using Mac os and installing Lightgbm

```bash
pip uninstall lightgbm

git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM ; cd LightGBM

export CXX=g++-8 CC=gcc-8

mkdir build ; cd build

cmake ..

make -j4
```

I can't install gcc@8 , gcc@7 and so on,
so I tried `brew install gcc` and it worked.

But `cmake ..` is failed. The error message:

```
Could NOT find OpenMP_C (missing: OpenMP_C_FLAGS OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES)
```

*error*
[image: error picture]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post pictures of logs / error messages. Posting such things as text instead means that others facing the same issue will be able to find your post from search engines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Could NOT find OpenMP_C

LightGBM uses OpenMP to parallelize some computations. If you are building small models and / or working with small datasets and do not need the speedups this parallelism offers, you can install `lightgbm` (the LightGBM Python package) from source without OpenMP support.

```bash
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM
cd LightGBM/python-package
pip install --install-option="--nomp" .
```

To build `lightgbm` with OpenMP support, install OpenMP on your system. Since you said you are on a Mac, you could (for example) use the Homebrew package manager to do that.

```bash
brew install libomp
```

Additional information on building the `lightgbm` can be found in [the LightGBM documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/python-package/README.rst).

Comment: ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement libomp (from versions: none)
how can i fix it?
my python version is 3.9.7

Comment: It seems that you ran `pip install libomp`. Please run `brew install libomp` as the answer and [the OpenMP documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/coder/ug/install-openmp-library-on-macos-platform.html) recommends.

Comment: okay i run brew install libomp but still got error

Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib

  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libomp.dylib' (no such file)

Comment: i solve the problem make conda env and conda install lightgbm it's working Am I right?

Comment: That sounds fine as well. I suspect that by using `conda`, `conda` took advantage of installing OpenMP for you.